# Which function should I use to find polygon overlaps with other polygon?

Tags: sql

I need a spatial function to detect given polygon is overlapping with existing polygons in the database.

I tried to use ST_Intersects(). It returns true if polygons touch each other. But In my case touching i okay.
I also tried ST_Overlaps(). This one returns false if 2 polygons same or contain one another. which is unacceptable.

Currently I'm using `SELECT COUNT(f) > 0 FROM fences f WHERE GeometryType(ST_INTERSECTION(f.region, :region)) = 'POLYGON'`
But this looks like can't use rtree indexes.

Is there a better way to detect polygons overlapping?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Desktop? Try the Topology Validation if you are using ArcGIS. Perhaps this video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCwR0z9mM7Y

Comment: @TMK No, I'm not using ArcGIS. I just assumed all SQL databases are the same for GIS functionality. Currently, I'm using MariaDB. I also looked into PostGIS documentation.

Comment: You could use Something like {ST_intersect()=true AND ST_touches=false} to get only "true" intersection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for **overlaps in *any* dimension** (i.e. ***allowing*** the `ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom)` case) use

```
ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

If you you need to ***disallow* border-only overlaps**, either use

```
ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
AND
NOT ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom)
```

if a direct index lookup is not supported by the DB engine, or

```
a.geom && b.geom
AND
ST_Relate(a.geom, b.geom, '2********')
```

if you can enforce index lookups explicitly - here for PostGIS via `a.geom && b.geom`, as `ST_Relate` itself is not sargable.

---

In either way, if you only want to check for existence of overlapping `fences`, run

```
SELECT
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      fences AS f
    WHERE
      <condition>
  )
;
```

which is much more scalable than the `COUNT(*) > 0` approach - if the `COUNT` interpretation is not specifically optimized in the DB engine.

Comment: Thanks for `SELECT EXISTS()` query. I needed a boolean response because `spring-data-jpa` can't tell if the query result has a row or not.

Comment: `ST_INTERSECTS(f.region, :region) AND NOT ST_TOUCHES(f.region, :region)` passed my tests. And utilizes rtree indexes.